# actionButton not working in XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have this block of code in my xcode project. I am having trouble being able to click the button and to make this work. The button displays in my simulator but does not work when I click it. Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on here? It was working at one point but now seems to have failed. Maybe I accidentally changed a build setting? Or simulator setting? Any thoughts would be appreciated!!

Code for the button

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *actionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                  target:self action:@selector(openWebLink)];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: actionButton,  nil];
[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

[actionButton release]; }
```

Here is the code for the action:

```
-(void)openWebLink{
// open a dialog with an OK and cancel button
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to apply for this job?"
                                                         delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:_toolbar];
[actionSheet release];  }
```

Comment: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` had you open your intertionEnable?

Comment: Define "does not work". Is the `openWebLink` method called (checking using the debugger)?

Comment: I just used your code in a demo project and it worked fine.